Caching of the Token Introspection
i have wrote the following OpenIddict event which cashes the ClaimsPrincipal for the given token after the Introspection.
public class CacheIntrospectionResponseHandler(IMemoryCache memoryCache, ILogger<CacheIntrospectionResponseHandler> logger)
    : IOpenIddictValidationHandler<OpenIddictValidationEvents.HandleIntrospectionResponseContext>
{
    public static OpenIddictValidationHandlerDescriptor Descriptor { get; }
        = OpenIddictValidationHandlerDescriptor.CreateBuilder<OpenIddictValidationEvents.HandleIntrospectionResponseContext>()
            .UseSingletonHandler<CacheIntrospectionResponseHandler>()
            .SetOrder(OpenIddictValidationHandlers.Introspection.PopulateClaims.Descriptor.Order + 2000)
            .SetType(OpenIddictValidationHandlerType.Custom)
            .Build();

    public ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictValidationEvents.HandleIntrospectionResponseContext context)
    {
        if (context is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Principal is not null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Token))
        {
            // Store the principal in the cache for 5 minutes.
            memoryCache.Set(context.Request.Token, context.Principal, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            
            logger.LogInformation("Cached introspection response for token '{Token}'.", context.Request.Token);
        }

        return default;
    }
}

I am currently struggling with retrieving this cashed ClaimsPrincipal before the Introspection request. What is an elegent way to retrieve the cashed ClaimsPrincipal before the Introspection and if it is cashed, use the cashed version instead of issuing a new Introspection request.

Do you want it to be STATIC?  With STATIC you can have only one instance of the object.

Well,  why don't you can create another handler that executes before the introspection handler in the OpenIddict pipeline. This handler will check if the token is present in the cache and return the cached ClaimsPrincipal if found. If not found, it will proceed with the introspection request.
